Issues accessing API data as string array
I am creating an API to receive data from a webhook and process it. I've set up a class to contain the POST data and can access all but one of the fields - the groups, which is set up as a string array.
I get that, if groups actually contained a key:value pair I could set it up as its own class and access it that way, but it doesn't. It looks like it should be simple but no matter what I do (array, list, dictionary) I can't get the values out. How can I access the two values in groups?
Webhook POST data:
{
  "first_name": "Test",
  "last_name": "Person",
  "groups": [
    "3831047f-7c38-4170-9789-40b8725bd9fa",
    "e5076e19-2dc6-4073-a467-e5d440a8ecd5"
  ],
  "email": "test.person@testr.com"
}

Class:
Public Class candData
  Public Property first_name As String
  Public Property last_name As String
  Public Property groups() As String
  Public Property email As String
End Class

Code:
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal params As candData)
  Dim strFN as string = params.first_name
  Dim strLN as string = params.last_name
  Dim strEM as string = params.email
  Dim aryGroups = Split(params.groups, ",") ' this returns an empty array
  Console.Log aryGroups(0)    ' this returns nothing
End Function


You already declared it as an array in candData.  What are the contents of params.groups when you run it?

Well, nothing.  That's the problem.  I have sorted it now though - see below.

OK, I've resolved this now - not sure why it was so hard!
I've defined the property as a list not an array:
 Public Property groups() As List(Of String)

And can now reference the values:
candData.groups.Item(0)

Seems obvious now!
